# Django Templates "for loops" not working correctly

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I'm trying to build template tags that take use a dictionary in `settings.py` to build a menu.

I have this as part of my template.

```
{% for menu_item in menu %}
     <li class="single-link"><a href="{{ menu_item.url }}" title="{{ menu_item.caption }}">{{ menu_item.caption }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

The context passed to this tag contain

```
context['menu'] = {'keywords': {'url': '#', 'caption': 'test'}, 'start': {'url': '#', 'caption': 'test'}, 'flippa': {'url': '#', 'caption': 'test'}}
```

`{{ menu.start.caption }}` works fine, however within my for loop, `menu_item` just contains just `'keywords'` or `'start'` or `'flippa'` and using `.` doesn't work at all.

**Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?**

Disclaimer: I've only been using django and python for a week!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Django templates, as in standard Python, using `for` on a dictionary just loops through the keys. You need to use the `.items()` method:

```
{% for key, value in menu.items %}
    <li class="single-link"><a href="{{ value.url }}" title="{{ value.caption }}">{{ value.caption }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

(Although I realise you're not actually using the key here, so you could just use `for value in menu.values`).

Also, note that a dictionary is probably not the right container for your items in any case, as you can't define the ordering. As armonge suggests, a list is probably better.

Comment: How would I use a list in this case? Just changing the context to a list rather then a dictionary did not work. I don't believe list has an items or values function?

Comment: With a list, you *can* just iterate through it: `for item in menu`.

Comment: That's not working, could it be because the list is actually being retrieved from settings.py using getattr?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm a terrible terrible idiot. (I just threw everything into a single list item).

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to have your menu be a list instead of a dictionary

context['menu'] = [{'url': '#', 'caption': 'test'},{'url': '#', 'caption': 'test'}, {'url': '#', 'caption': 'test'}]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use lists.